# Angular 2 HTTP module does not load via system.js: Error: Cannot find name 'Http'

Tags: angular

Angular latest beta.0 error: Error:(15, 25) TS2304: Cannot find name 'Http'.
tried diff things like

```
import {Http} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http.dev';
import {Http} from 'angular2/bundles/http';
```

all with no luck :(

here is my component:

```
  ///<reference path="../../typings/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts"/>
///<reference path="../../typings/zone.js/zone.js.d.ts"/>

import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Inject} from 'angular2/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    private _val:number;

    constructor(@Inject(Http) http:Http) {
        this._val = Math.random();
    }

    public showAlert() {
        alert(`here is an alert ${this._val}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be that System.js is getting confused as to which file to grab (js or ts), seems like it's something that broken in recent release of ng2 beta

Comment: Do you have `defaultJSExtensions: true` in your system config?

Comment: thanks drew, just saw that.. I found the answer on the web, but your answer is right... needed to add defaultJSExtensions: true

Comment: No problem. I'd suggest editing your question / title to reflect what the problem turned out to be

Answer (score 0):

as of ng2 beta needed to change my system.js to

```
 <script>
System.config({
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: 'typescript',
  packages: {
    'component': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}
  },
  typescriptOptions: {emitDecoratorMetadata: true}
});
System.import('./component/App.ts')
```

hopes it helps someone...

Comment: this made things worse for me. Now none of my modules load :/

Comment: same here, nothing loads now.